# processing data from json gets me unhashable type 'slice' error - python

Tags: json, python-3.x

The source

```
#make an api call and store the response
url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/9884165.json'
r = requests.get(url)
```

here is the problem

```
for submission_id in submission_ids[:30]:
```

here is the snippet of the code

```
#process information about each submission
submission_ids = r.json()
submission_dicts = []
for submission_id in submission_ids[:30]:
#make a separate API call for each submission
url = ('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + 
        str(submission_id) + '.json') 

submission_r = requests.get(url)
print(submission_r.status_code)
response_dict = submission_r.json()

submission_dict = {
    'title': response_dict['title'],
    'link': 'http://news,ycombinator.com/item?id=' + str(submission_id),
    'comments': response_dict.get('descendants', 0),
}
submission_dict.append(submission_dict)
```

whats the solution for unhashable slice in this case?

Comment: You need to show us the value of `submission_ids`. The problem is that it is probably a `dict` and you can't slice dictionaries. Perhaps you want `submission_ids[<key>][:30]` instead?

Comment: Also you're going to run into an error later with the comma in between `http://news` and `ycombinator`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get the list of numbers in the response...
If this is the case, here is the way;

```
url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/9884165.json'
r = requests.get(url)
response = r.json()
submission_ids = response["kids"]
submission_dicts = []
for submission_id in submission_ids[:30]:
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying @Faizal Mustafa given solution below i realized something after a few hours of troubleshooting. I have the wrong source, because the next error it gives me was

`File "hn_submissions.py", line 23, in <module>
'title': response_dict["title"],
 KeyError: 'title'`

After checking the source, truth be told, there is no title.

Solution, changed the first source to

```
url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
```

Thanks for the contribution everyone.